# Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null error

Tags: php, mysql, oop

there were a lot of answers related to this, but I couldn't find useful information. I'm trying to connect to the database and insert user's entered values into it, but I got this error and I seriously don't know what I am doing wrong. I've created 2 different classes in 2 different files, one is connection.php and the other is users.php (for insterting the users into the database) Could someone help me to solve this?

Here is my connection.php file:

```
<?php

class Connection {
public $dbh;
    // Setting Database Source Name (DSN)
public function __construct() {
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=employees';
// Setting options
 $options = array (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
// Making the connection to the database
try {
$this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, 'root', '', $options); 
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
$this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
$connection = new connection();
?>
```

And here is my users.php file:

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include 'connection.php';
class Users {
public $name;
public $surname;
public $employmentDate;
public $connection;
public function __construct($connection)
{
$this->connection = $connection;
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$this->name = $_POST['name'];
$this->surname = $_POST['surname'];
$this->employmentDate = $_POST['employmentDate'];
}
}
// Inserting users values to the database table
public function insertUserValues() {
 $query= 'INSERT INTO employee (name,surname,employment_date)
 VALUES (:name,:surname,:employmentDate)';
 $stmt = $this->connection->dbh->prepare($query);
 $stmt->bindValue(':name',$this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindValue(':surname',$this->surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->bindValue(':employmentDate',$this->employmentDate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $stmt->execute();
}
}
$users = new Users($connection);
$users->insertUserValues();
?>
```

I got this error on users.php line 27, which is:

`$stmt->execute();`

And it says:

`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null`

I know here are a lot of code, but thanks if someone will try to help me...

Comment: You're trying to insert a `null` value into the `name` column, which doesn't allow nulls.  Either remove that restriction from the column or provide a value for the column.  (It would appear that `$this->name` is `null`.)

Comment: But I've assigned a variable $_POST['name'] to it, how it can be null value? I don't get it...

Comment: For one thing, that dependency on `$_POST` in your class is kind of a poor design.  The value should be required on the constructor, not assumed to exist in some external dependency.  As for having a null value, clearly that dependency didn't have what you expected it to have.  If a value doesn't exist, it's `null`.  That's kind of what `null` means.

Answer (score 6):

The error seems quite clear.  You have a column in the table that cannot take on a `NULL` value.

I would speculate that it is not one of the column where you are explicitly providing a value (`name`, `surname`, `employment_date`).  You need to look at the definition of the table and look for another column defined as `NOT NULL` (or perhaps `PRIMARY KEY` with no default value).

Comment: Meh, I can't find any mistakes in my table columns :/

Comment: @Godron Linoff found in my table column value id, which is `PRIMARY KEY`, what should I do with it? Sorry for dumb questions, but I'm just trying to learn

Comment: @MKD: Ideally it should be an `AUTOINCREMENT` column.  Though the error message is referring to the `name` column, not the `id` column.  You're trying to write a `null` value to `name`, which doesn't allow nulls.

Comment: @David so how can I solve this problem? What I need to be looking for? My table are from 4 rows: `id, name, surname, employment_date` and the id is `AUTO INCREMENT`. Meh, I really can't get it

Comment: @MKD: You have exactly two choices: (1) Provide a value for the `name` column (your code is *trying* to do this, but an assumption about the existence of a value in that variable is incorrect); or (2) Change the column to allow `null` values.  It really can't be any more straightforward than that.  If a value is *required*, then a value is *required*.

Comment: @David last question. As you said, I've put the check mark in my table rows to allow `null` values and now user's are entering to the database successfully, but here is the question, is it done correctly? I'm talking about the table and `null` values. Can it be done like that?

Besides that, thank you for your time really really much! Appreciate it!

Comment: @MKD: Whether or not you want `null` values in that column is really up to you.  Mechanically a column can allow nulls, or it can reject nulls.  Both are *physically* possible options.  The logic of whether or not you *should* use one option vs. another is your choice based on the system you're designing.  (I would generally think that a "name" value shouldn't be `null`, but there are certainly cases where it can be.)

Comment: @David Well man, thank you very much for your time, you really helped me a lot, I've been dealing with that problem a couple days, so.. Thank you and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the column is marked as Primary key or auto_increment if you are using it that way, or mark it as null if you want to store null.

Answer (score 1):

It could be any problem related to the field. Check the HTML for spelling, confusion between name and value, etc. 
Your field may be empty because it is not finding the value you actually entered in the field because there is no such field per code (only on your screen). In my case, I had

`$new_user = array(
            "id" => $_POST ['id'],
            "fname" => $_POST['firstname']`

But the HTML was using fname and fname for both value and name.

And there was the first error: name="firstname" was written as vname="firstname"
Then the confusion with name and HTML value.

You didn't post your HTML. The error is perhaps there.